# Removing a specific label from the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given the data and chart below, how do I remove the category that is shown as "NA" from the legend? I just want the legend to show the colours for categories `A`, `B`, and `C`.

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- tibble(Time_dim = rep(1:10, 10),
                 Category = c(rep(NA, 10), rep(c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 10)), 3)),
                 Attribute = c(rep("alpha", 10), rep("beta", 30), rep("omega", 30), rep("theta", 30)),
                 Data = runif(100))
mydata$Category <- factor(mydata$Category)
mydata$Attribute <- factor(mydata$Attribute)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Time_dim, y = Data, colour = Category)) +
geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ Attribute, ncol = 1, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: The answer provided in the other thread didn't work with my data, but the answer provided by @aosmith works perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `breaks` in your `color` scale to only the categories you want displayed.

In your case you can use the `levels` of your color factor.

`scale_color_discrete(breaks = levels(mydata$Category))`

Answer (score 1):

add this to the ggplot

```
+ scale_colour_manual(breaks=c("A", "B", "C"), values=c("red", "green", "blue"))
```